# regarding using urllib3 to replace urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, urllib3

I was trying to use the following code segment. I am using Python 3, which has `urllib3` instead of urllib2. I would like to know how replace this part `fh = urllib2.urlopen('http://people.ku.edu/~gbohling/geostats/WGTutorial.zip')
    data = fh.read()` in `urllib3`. Thanks.

```
clusterfile = 'ZoneA.dat'
if not os.path.isfile(clusterfile):
    fh = urllib2.urlopen('http://people.ku.edu/~gbohling/geostats/WGTutorial.zip')
    data = fh.read()
    fobj = StringIO.StringIO(data)
    myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(fobj,'r')
    myzip.extract(clusterfile)
    fobj.close()
    fh.close()
```

Comment: No, urllib3 is a third-party library. The replacement for urllib2 in Python 3 is [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request), and you use it in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In python 3 `urlopen` is part of `urllib.request`  so you have to modify your imports:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

If you want your script to run in python 2 and python 3 you can use:

```
try:  
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:  
    from urllib.request import urlopen
```